# aws s3 moving objects into glacier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

**Initial_State:**

I have two S3 buckets termed as `input_bucket` and `output_bucket`. every second, my `input_bucket` filled with csv_files.

**My Requirment:**
i want to move csv_files present in `input_bucket(STANDARD_CLASS)` to `output_bucker(Glacier storage class)`

**Note:** I want to move csv_files(40 days older from the date of creation)

please suggest some solution for this

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to move csv files from one bucket to the other only if they are 40 days old?  So for the first 40 days a new file is only in `input_bucket`, and then after 40 days, it is moved to `output_bucker`?

Comment: Hi Marcin, you are right. First 40 days CSV files will be there in input_bucket(standard class).  Then I want those to be moved to another output_bucket(Glacier class). In output_bucket, I want to permanently store csv_files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

**1 Using replication** (**Easy and Recommended**)

You don't need to write any code to achieve it. This solution will replicate files created in `input_bucket` to `output_bucket` and then delete them from `input_bucket` after 40 days.

- Create [replication rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) between source (input_bucket) and source (output_bucket)
- Add Expiration [using S3 lifecycle configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html) in the source bucket.

E.g.

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
  <Rule>
    <ID>Transition Rule</ID>
    <Status>Enabled</Status>
    <Expiration>
      <Days>40</Days>
      <StorageClass>S3 Glacier</StorageClass>
    </Expiration>
  </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

**2 Using custom application** **(Not recommended)**

Enable S3 triggers and then use Lambda function to create Dynamodb item with [TTL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) enabled for 40 days. Dynamodb item should contain the S3 object path. You will also need to enable [Dynamodb stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-streams.html) to trigger a Lambda function that would copy the object from `input_bucket` to `output_bucket` and then delete it from the source. This solution is expensive and not recommended.